# How to use SourceSansPro to match design cross browsers

Tags: html, css, fonts

I used SourceSansPro to match the font in design, FF, Safari seem ok. Chrome and IE 11 have issue.

Here is the design for the font (due to proxy, cannot upload, but have a look at FF and Safari)

Here is code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro"
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
    />
    <style>
      .fontStyle {
        font-style: normal;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-family: "SourceSansPro", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        color: #000;
        font-weight: 500;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <div class="fontStyle">
    Drop a file here
  </div>
</html>
```

It seems the bold is quite different in IE and Chrome.
In summary, need to make the font style in IE and Chrome, same as FF and Safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the code you're using there only include the 400-weight font, and browsers have different reactions when trying to get a bold version of a lighter font - some make it bold themselves, or just load a different font. In order to load the font weights you want (along with italic versions), you can use a line like this:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,900,900i&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

With the versions/weights separated with commas.

If you go to the [Google Font page for this](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Source+Sans+Pro?selection.family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,900,900i), you can click "Customize" to select which fonts to include, and it'll generate the embed code for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style>
        .fontStyle {
            font-style: normal;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
            color: #000;
            font-weight: 500;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<div class="fontStyle">
    Drop a file here
</div>
</html>
```